# Visualise two quantities in the same data matrix

Tags: data-visualization

**Question:** How to best visualise two observables $(p, q)$ for each pair $(x, y)$ in a data matrix?

My current ansatz is to plot $p\in[0,1]$ as the dot size and $q\in [0, 1]$ as the dot color (for $p$ close to one the circle starts to fill out the complete square):
[image: Rough Mockup of data matrix with two quantities.]
However, I am not completely happy because the contrast around the circle edges draws away a lot of attention from the color code. That makes it hard to focus on color-only (observable $q$).

Comment: Could you please tell us the meaning of the data, the objective of the visualization, and the intended audience?  Without such guidance, there will be no objective way to establish what "best" might be.